Steps to add okhttp to existing Java project in Eclipse
I'm old-school and so have always just added jar files to the build path in Eclipse (4.26.0), but I want to modernize.  Everything I see talks about maven, so I went into Window > Show View > Other... and selected Maven Repositories, but can't find anything to do there.
Then I tried right-click New > Other...> Maven > Maven Project which directs me to Select and Archetype, but under "All Catalogs", I do not find "okhttp".
I see that https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/4.12.0 exists, and that's what I want in my project. I tried "Add Remote Catalog...", but when I put https://mvnrepository.com/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml as the catalog file, it says "Remote catalog is empty", so my guess at what the catalog file xml file name is can't be right.  I don't see where on mvnrepository.com they tell me what the catalog xml file URL is.
How can I add okhttp to my Eclipse project? Should I just give up and go back to jar files?

If you are really old school, you should learn to run maven from the command line and add dependencies manually to the Pom.  Might be a step learning curve but you are a bit behind.

You want to add OkHttp 4.12.0 as a dependency, right? In the New Maven Project dialog, check the first checkbox Create a simple project (skip archetype selection). And then open the created pom.xml file to add the dependency. By the way, your Eclipse IDE is six releases behind. Please upgrade.

Here's an Eclipse-centric answer for the uninitiated.  It does not answer the original question (adding Maven dependency to an existing project), but instead provides a path to make a new Maven project, to which the other project code may be added.
In Eclipse, create a new Maven project: New > Project... > Maven > Maven Project Select create simple project checkbox.

Group Id and Artifact Id are things you define, so change those to suit your project:

When you click "Finish", it sets up the Maven structure for you:

You can then add a dependency to the project:

For my example, I wanted to add okhttp, so I navigated to the repository  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/4.12.0 and saw:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>4.12.0</version>
</dependency>

After putting those three entries into the Add Dependency dialog, and hitting OK, this popped up almost instantly:

I am now able to use OkHttpClient:


If you want to switch to maven, it is essentially four steps:

add a pom.xml to your project, at top level
adjust the project's file structure, so the folders / packages for what you declared as groupId/artifactId in the pom.xml
build your project with mvn clean package
(You can later add the exec plugin, to conveniently start after build.)
add the okhttp dependency you are interested in, by adding the xml you see on mvncentral to the pom.xml's dependencies tag.

I'd recommend to use a template hello world project, so you can conveniently start off with something that works, and inspect file structure, find inspiration from... You can create such a sample project with an archetype:
  mvn archetype:generate \
  -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow \
  -DartifactId=MavenHelloWorld \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart \
  -DinteractiveMode=false

(replace com.stackoverflow by whatever reversed domain fits you as a developer / company)

A while ago I've created a "getting started with maven" page for my students, where I explain layout, minimal pom.xml and some off-the-shelf maven configuration building blocks. Might be a good side-read to get started with the project migration.

